# Can't search for a record in sqlite database using tkinter as a gui to enter the name of the record I am searching for (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am making a program for a library using a database to store details about books, with tkinter as a gui. A feature of the program is where the user can enter the name of a book and it will search the database and return records with books containing that name. Here is the code I currently have for this feature:

```
def bookSearch(event):
top = Toplevel()
top.title("Book Search")

Label(top, text = "Enter the name of the book you are searching for:      ").grid()

bookSearchEntry = Entry(top)
bookSearchEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

getRecord = c.execute("SELECT * FROM bookList WHERE BookName = (?)", bookSearchEntry.get())

def printRecords(event):
    for row in getRecord:
        t = Text(top, height = 400, width = 50)
        t.pack()
        t.insert(END, getRecord)

bookSearchButton = Button(top, text = "Search", command = printRecords)
bookSearchButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
```

I am getting this error message:

```
getRecord = c.execute("SELECT * FROM bookList WHERE BookName = (?)", bookSearchEntry.get())
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

I have seen other posts saying to add a comma to make a tuple but even with

```
getRecord = c.execute("SELECT * FROM bookList WHERE BookName = (?)", bookSearchEntry.get,())
```

I still get an error message, however, it's this error message:

```
getRecord = c.execute("SELECT * FROM bookList WHERE BookName = (?)", bookSearchEntry.get,())
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I have been stuck on this for ages, any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Try `(bookSearchEntry.get(),)` - you need to wrap the response in a tuple.

Comment: what does `bookSearchEntry.get()` return? It seems slightly odd to me that you're running the SQL query as soon as the entry widget is instantiated.

Comment: You are doing the search about a microsecond after creating the widget. Your users are going to have to type really, really fast!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the second argument to the execute method has to be a tuple. So you should write it as:

```
getRecord = c.execute("SELECT * FROM bookList WHERE BookName = (?)", (bookSearchEntry.get(),))
```

Comment: (bookSearchEntry.get(),) still gives the first error message of the incorrect number of bindings. I don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

I will focus only on the first error and ignore the second one since it appears to deflect from the core issue.

This is the error message stated: 
`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.`

When I try it in my setup, it gives me similar error: 
`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 16 supplied.`

The 16 indicates a value which I input "Melamine Ashtray" which comprises 16 characters. So clearly, the WHERE condition in your code appears to have no characters i.e. 0 content.

1. Your code is failing because when *bookSearchEntry.get(*) happens, there is nothing to get because it is not inside your *bookSearchButton* command. It is better to bind the get() with an event such as Button click.
2. Its not clear how the cursor will save values directly into *getRecords* without a *fetchall()*
3. A variable is needed to get the values which is declared as z in the following example.

I have made some modifications and rewritten your code in better sequence as follows, it works:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sqlite3

def printRecords():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('your_DB_name')
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select column_name  from table_name where  book_name = ?", (z.get(),))
    connection.commit()
    variablename = cur.fetchall()
    print variablename

root = Tk()
root.title ( "Search a Book")

z= StringVar()

#Label
Label(root, text = "Enter the name of the book you are searching for:      ").grid()
#Textbox
bookSearchEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = z)
bookSearchEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
#Button
bookSearchButton = Button(root, text = "Search", command = printRecords)
bookSearchButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```